# Ошибка при вызове метода $('#id').load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Доброго времени суток.

Бэк: ASP.NET Core 1.1.

В данном действии происходит только **подготовка** запроса к отправке

При загрузке в элемент данных с помощью `$('#id').load()` возникает ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '*' of undefined

Версия, которая работала месяц назад, тоже не работает(сделал откат, тогда работала).

Прошерстив место возникновения ошибка(jQuery метод, у них в библиотеки), узнал что при отправке запроса **на сервер** `dataTypes="*"`.

Вот кусок кода из библиотеки ***JQuery(не моя)***, где происходит ошибка:

```
// Set the Accepts header for the server, depending on the dataType    
jqXHR.setRequestHeader(
            "Accept",
            s.dataTypes[ 0 ] && s.accepts[ s.dataTypes[ 0 ] ] ?
                s.accepts[ s.dataTypes[ 0 ] ] +
                    ( s.dataTypes[ 0 ] !== "*" ? ", " + allTypes + "; q=0.01" : "" ) :
                s.accepts[ "*" ]
        );
```

Попробовал использовать $.ajax, чтобы явно указать dataType:

```
$.ajax(url,
                            { accepts: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', dataType: 'json',method: 'GET' });
```

dataType = '*' также, но ошибка уже возникает на строке с вызовом

```
        // Uppercase the type
        s.type = s.type.toUpperCase();
```

Где происходит повышение в регистр **типа** запроса. Явно это указал в ajax и эта часть работает корректно, но ошибка теперь та же(просто это строка идет перед той, где происходит проверка на *).

Подскажите, куда копать. Эта часть не трогалась месяц.

**Update 1:**

Cкрин объекта s

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Update 2**

Код на интерфейсе программы, на котором возникает ошибка.

Переменные передаются нормально. Напомню, что я уже откатился на месяц назад, когда все идеально работало и эта ошибка там тоже присутствует.

```
$('#details').load("/Drive/EditDelete?M2Mid=" + M2Mid);
```

Comment: "При загрузке в элемент данных с помощью $('#id').load() возникает ошибка:" - можно код?

Comment: @PROPHESSOR добавил в Update 2

Comment: Тут самый очевидный вариант - проблема в backend

Comment: @PROPHESSOR "Версия, которая работала месяц назад, тоже не работает(сделал откат, тогда работала)." Это первое, что пришло в голову, поэтому и откатился.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из-за накопления количества глупых ошибок мы ушли с платформы ASP.NET Core и вэба вообще(возможно мы просто не умеем в вэб)

Поэтому ответ на вопрос остался тайной, покрытой дымкой неизбежного мрака.

Answer (score 0):

У вас функция не видит toUpperCase() не видит данные которые вы пытаетесь передать, по этому выходит undefined. Проверьте что вы пытаетесь передавать.

Comment: Тут не все так просто. Прочитайте внимательнее все